# Pasting the RMSE and MAE next to a forecast in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some locations with products that I need to forecast. It's around 300 location-product combinations. One plot is always the location and all the products (like in the image). Now I want to print the RMSE and MAE for each product next to the graph in the plot. They are calculated and stored in `data_accuracy`  in their own columns, but I have no Idea how to print them into the plot.  Is there a feasible way of doing it?

Ps: I know about the out of bounds error. It just happens with this example data but the results work as normal.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(tsibble)
    library(fable)
    library(lubridate)
    
    data_ts <- data.frame(sales_year = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2016-01-01",
 "2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01",
 "2018-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01"), product = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c",
 "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), sales = c(6, 11, 13, 6, 2, 6, 11, 12, 10,  4, 12, 2,
 17, 6, 8))
    data_ts <- data_ts%>%
      mutate(sales_year = year(sales_year)) 
    
    data_ts <- tsibble(data_ts, index = sales_year, key = product)
    
    data_train <- data_ts %>%
      filter(sales_year < "2018-01-01")
    
    data_ses <- data_train %>%
      model(ETS(sales ~ error("A") + trend("N") + season("N")))
    data_ses_fc <- data_ses %>%
      forecast(h = 1)
    
    data_accuracy <- data_ses_fc %>%
      accuracy(data_ts)
    
    data_ses_fc %>%
      autoplot(data_ts) +
      geom_line(aes(y = .fitted), col="red",
                data = augment(data_ses))
```

[image: Plot now without the RMSE & MA writen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
data_accuracy <- data_ses_fc %>%
  accuracy(data_ts) %>% 
  mutate(res = paste0("RMSE: ",round(RMSE,2),"\n",
                      "MAE: ",round(MAE,2)))

data_ses_fc %>%
  autoplot(data_ts) +
  geom_line(aes(y = .fitted), col="red",
            data = augment(data_ses)) +
  geom_text(data=data_accuracy,aes(x = 2016,y=12,group=product,label=res))
```

[image: Generated plot]

Comment: That works fine. I hoped to write it outside of the graph, but that works too. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: I solved it through just increasing the x so it fits the data nicely.